# Linux Headers and Updates

Tags: symbolic-link

If I create a symbolic link from `linux-headers` in `/usr/src` and then an update comes along where my `uname -r` output changes, does that symbolic link get updated as well?  Or do I have to switch the symlink to the new `uname -r` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A symbolic link is static to a location. This means that if you make a symbolic link for `linux-headers-3.13.0-46` for example, that is the location it will link to, no matter what. That being the case, you would have to switch or recreate the symbolic link each time you update.